# Descent for $K(1)$-local spectra

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, infinity-categories, descent, chromatic-homotopy

For odd primes, we have an equalizer diagram for the $K(1)$- local sphere given by
$$L_{K(1)}S \rightarrow  K{{ \xrightarrow{\Psi^g}}\atop{\xrightarrow[i_K ]  {}}} K$$
where $g$ is a topological generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ and $\Psi^g$ denotes the Adams operation. Now we can apply the functor $Mod(-): \textrm{Spectra} \to \textrm{Symmetric monoidal infinity categories} $ and then apply the functor $L_{K(1)}$. This gives us a diagram of the form
$$L_{K(1)}Sp \rightarrow  Mod_{K(1)}(K){{ \xrightarrow{\Psi^g}}\atop{\xrightarrow[i_K ]  {}}} Mod_{K(1)}(K)$$ where $L_{K(1)}Sp$ are the $K(1)$-local spectra and $Mod_{K(1)}(K)$ are the $K(1)$-local $K$ modules.
Now is this an equalizer diagram?

I have been told that this is most likely true, so I was just wondering if there was a reference for this statement. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not quite true: need to require a $p$-adic continuity condition for the $\Psi^g$-semilinear automorphism of the $K(1)$-local $K$-module.  You can see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.11622.pdf Proposition 3.10 for a slight variant which also works at the prime 2.

Comment: Thanks! I just have a question regarding terminology. So what does mod p homotopy groups mean? Are they maps from Mod p Moore spectrum?

Comment: That's right, at least up to a shift.  I usually think of it as the honest homotopy groups of the (homotopy) cofiber of the multiplication by p map.  P.S.: if you found the proof of Proposition 3.10 a little hard to follow, I think a couple more details will be added in an updated version :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! An updated version would be very helpful :)